# Accessing data from cell arrays at the same time

Tags: matlab, cell-array

If `A` is a `(x,y)` cell array having `n` cells and each of them is a vector of size `(m,n)` and of type `double`.

```
Example: If A is a 1x2 cell array
A = 
[100x1 double]  [100x1 double]
```

Suppose I want to access the first element of each cells at the same time, how can we do so?

Similarly, if we need to access the `i`th element from every cell, how do we generalise the code?

Comment: If the size of the array in each cell is the same, why use a cell array instead of a 3D array?

Comment: Would it be faster than using a cell array? I am dealing with very large matrices.

Comment: It is very likely, yes.

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to convert a 2D matrix to 3D array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cell creation with two 1*10 arrays:

```
A {1} = zeros(1,10)  ;
A {2} = zeros (1,10) ;
```

> A = 
>       [1x10 double]    [1x10 double]

Adding some data which will be used for fetching later:

```
A {1}(5) = 5 ;
A {2}(5) = 10 ;
```

Routine to fetch the data at same index from both arrays inside cell:

```
cellfun (@(x) x(5),A)
```

> ans =
>            5    10

Comment: Is there a way to do this without  using cellfun()?

Comment: And why are you assigning 5 and 10?

Comment: @EBH: Thanks a lot for explaining my solution.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

As User1551892 suggested, you could use **cellfun**. Another way is to restruct the cell to a matrix first.
The speed on the operation depends on the number of cells and the size of the matrix within each cell.

```
% Number of cells
x = 3;
y = 2;

% Size of matrix 
m = 1;
n = 100;

% Add some random numbers 
A = cell(x,y);
for i = 1:numel(A)
    A{i} = round(rand(m,n)*100);
end

% Index to pick in each matrix
idx = 5;

% Convert to matrix
B = [A{:}];

% Pick the number
val = B(idx:(n*m):end);
```

Doing som tic-toc measurements, the method above is faster for the example values. As long as the one of n or m is small the method is ok.
But if both m and n grows large, cellfun is better (faster)

```
val = cellfun(@(x) x(idx), A);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be to simply access the cell elements directly , for example we have a cell like you defined

```
A{1}(1:10) = randi([2 5],1,10);
A{2}(1:10) = randi([2 5],1,10);
```

now if you want to access the ith elements simply declare i and they will be retrieved in the matrix below

```
 i = 3;

ObsMatrix = [A{1}(i) A{2}(i)]

ObsMatrix =

     2     5
```

If A has unknown number of cell you can simply use a for loop , It will pick ith element from every cell index and put it in ObsMat

```
i = 3;
for j=1:numel(A)
ObsMat(end + 1) = A{j}(3);
end
```

cellfun is also a wrapper function for `for` loop

```
ObsMat =

     2     5
```

Comment: I don't want to call A more than once as you have shown. I would want to use a generalised one instead. That's because A is going to be very large.